# Menu falling out of screen on website

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this website
http://2xthuis.dev.xsbyte.net

Working on it for some time to make the design work, but can't get it to.

The problem right now is:
On a screen <1400px wide the left menu starts disappearing on the left side (out of the screen).
How would I solve this problem, I've tried position relative and working with right instead of left.

The menu has to stay on the screen no matter what.

Comment: But where? There's no room

Comment: I guess the menu should get a smaller width?

Comment: Read about `Responsive CSS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not reinvent the wheel and use a commonly used library for responsive user interfaces - [Bootstrap by Twitter](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

it has a really cool and simple grid system which lets you build responsive web design in a few minutes. if you need any help, please let me know in comments.

Comment: Hi Laurynas, thanks for your post. Would I have to rebuild the whole website or can I use this to improve the website? From what I read on the website it's something you use to start off with.

Comment: bootstrap is kind of a base on which you build your website user interface. it is really worth to rebuild the website. When you figure out how the grid system works it is only a matter of a few hours ;)